# How to trigger / debug backdoor functionality in Xamarin.Forms.UITesting?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, ui-testing

I'm trying to add a BackdoorMethod to a Xamarin.Forms application to bypass the login (IDP - opened in chrome browser) step. I have the feeling that the method is not getting triggered, but not sure, and I don't know how could I make sure about it.

I've read the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/uitest/working-with-backdoors

Check this thread: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/85821/xamarin-uitest-backdoor-on-droid-with-splash-screen-how-do-i-access-my-mainactivity

Checked this example: https://github.com/brminnick/UITestSampleApp/tree/master/Src

In the **MainActivity.cs** file I've defined the BackdoorMethod:

```
[Preserve, Export(nameof(BypassLoginScreen))]   
public string BypassLoginScreen()
{
  // some additional code here. the code is working, when I called it 
  // directly from OnCreate it was executed without any error
  return "called";
}
```

From the test case i'm trying to invoke it like:

```
public constructorMethod(Platform platform) 
{
  this.platform = platform;
  app = AppInitializer.StartApp(platform);
  var result = app.Invoke("BypassLoginScreen"); // result == "<VOID>"
}
```

I'm not getting any error message, the method simply not called, or not returns anything. (or i don't know what's happening there with it, because breakpoint also not working as the app started from the device)

Answer (score 0):

This should be already working. I have similar code and it works for me.
you can add inside your function

```
 Android.Util.Log.WriteLine(Android.Util.LogPriority.Info, "BypassLoginScreen", $"Some text as info");
```

And observe the result in Device Logs, Filter by BypassLoginScreen to see if there is any log created with the tag BypassLoginScreen